# Product2 field in OrderItem Object

Tags: order, orderitem, product

When I ran below query in workbench/developer console

`SELECT product2 FROM OrderItem`

am getting below error

> No such column 'Product2' on entity 'OrderItem'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

But I see Product2 field in Order Product I am not sure why I am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no direct binding to the Product table from Order Lines, the link is actually through PricebookEntries. So the SOQL to get the ProductId would be:

`select Pricebookentry.Product2Id from OrderItem`

Answer (score 1):

credit to [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) for noting that the Product2 relationship on OrderItem is part of the latest API versions and the SOQL query above should work with API version 57.0

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
SELECT product2id from OrderItem
```

We do not have orders enabled but this works for OpportunitLineItems which is its close cousin.

Comment: Same error message : No such column 'product2id' on entity 'OrderItem'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.